# Helper of Facebook Plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins, cakephp-2.3

I use the Facebook plugin for Cakephp 2 developed by nick at webtechnick.
I installed the plugin in the following folder **/var/www/tree/Plugin/Facebook/View/Helper**
In bootstrap.php I got

```
CakePlugin::load('Facebook');
```

My AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Cookie', 'Session','DebugKit.Toolbar');
    public $helpers = array( 'Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time', 'Text', 'Setting', 'Number','Facebook.Facebook');
    public $uses = array('Setting');
```

and when loading the homepage I get the following error

**Helper class FacebookHelper could not be found.**

Any idea why CakePhp doesn't find the Helper in my plugin?

Comment: I noticed in my Debug Kit toolbar the Facebook plugin isn't registered. though not sure if that means it isn't load the Facebook Helper. I put the following code
        if (CakePlugin::loaded('Facebook')) {
            echo "yes";
        }
        else {
            echo "no";
        }
        
and it looks like I loaded the plugin.

Comment: Ok. The problem was that I didn't use the correct version of the Plugin. I used git clone to download it and it works perfectly.